# Phonegap IOS App Image ZOOM Multitouch

Tags: javascript, cordova, multi-touch, iso

I'm developing an app with Phonegap for IOS. I would zoom and move an image contained in a box div (overflow hidden) with the finger: multitouch for zoom in and out and touchmove for move the image.

Is it possible? and how?

I'm looking with Google for the solution but I don't find it!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do it.

Probably the easiest way is to use iScroll4's pinch/zoom feature: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Answer (score 0):

You should check this tutorial about Multitouch and HTML/JS. It works with PhoneGap applications too. http://www.appliness.com/multitouch-with-hammer-js/

Answer (score 0):

this one is a nice simple tutorial in using iscroll4 for image zooming:

http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/adding-picture-zooming-to-your-phonegap-app-with-iscroll4/

helped me a bit in my phonegap app. now, if i could only figure out how to use it with an svg. hmmm..